# OpenCV: How to use AffineTransformer

Tags: opencv, transformation, matching, shapes

Hello and thanks for your help.

I would like to test the use of shapes for matching in OpenCV and managed to do the matching part. 
To locate the rotated shape, i tought the [AffineTransformer Class](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/dc/d83/classcv_1_1AffineTransformer.html) would be the right choice. As I don't know how the matching would work internally, it would be nice if someone has a link where the proceedings are described.

As  shawshank mentioned my following code throw an Assertion failed-error because the variable matches is empty when passed to estimateTransformation function. Does anybody know how to use this function in the right way -respectively what it really does?

```
#include<opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include<algorithm>
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

bool rotateImage(Mat src, Mat &dst, double angle)
{
    // get rotation matrix for rotating the image around its center
    cv::Point2f center(src.cols/2.0, src.rows/2.0);
    cv::Mat rot = cv::getRotationMatrix2D(center, angle, 1.0);
    // determine bounding rectangle
    cv::Rect bbox = cv::RotatedRect(center,src.size(), angle).boundingRect();
    // adjust transformation matrix
    rot.at<double>(0,2) += bbox.width/2.0 - center.x;
    rot.at<double>(1,2) += bbox.height/2.0 - center.y;

    cv::warpAffine(src, dst, rot, bbox.size());
    return 1;
}


static vector<Point> sampleContour( const Mat& image, int n=300 )
{

    vector<vector<Point>> contours;           
    vector<Point> all_points;                      
    findContours(image, contours, cv::RETR_LIST, cv::CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);
    for (size_t i=0; i <contours.size(); i++)
    {
        for (size_t j=0; j<contours[i].size(); j++)
        {
           all_points.push_back(contours[i][j]);
        }
    }

    int dummy=0;
    for (int add=(int)all_points.size(); add<n; add++)
    {
        all_points.push_back(all_points[dummy++]);
    }

    // shuffel
    random_shuffle(all_points.begin(), all_points.end());
    vector<Point> sampled;
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        sampled.push_back(all_points[i]);
    }
    return sampled;
}


int main(void)
{
    Mat img1, img2;
    vector<Point> img1Points, img2Points;
    float distSC, distHD;

    // read images
    string img1Path = "testimage.jpg";
    img1 = imread(img1Path, IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
    rotateImage(img1, img2, 45);
    imshow("original", img1);
    imshow("transformed", img2);
    waitKey();

    // Contours
    img1Points = sampleContour(img1);
    img2Points = sampleContour(img2);

    //Calculate Distances
    Ptr<ShapeContextDistanceExtractor> mysc = createShapeContextDistanceExtractor();
    Ptr<HausdorffDistanceExtractor> myhd = createHausdorffDistanceExtractor();

    distSC = mysc->computeDistance( img1Points, img2Points );
    distHD = myhd -> computeDistance( img1Points, img2Points );

    cout << distSC << endl << distHD << endl;
    vector<DMatch> matches;
    Ptr<AffineTransformer> transformerHD = createAffineTransformer(0);
    transformerHD -> estimateTransformation(img1Points, img2Points, matches);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you tell what was the assertion error?

Comment: of course, i get this error: OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (src.cols > 0 && src.rows > 0) in warpAffine, file /build/opencv/src/opencv-3.2.0/modules/imgproc/src/imgwarp.cpp, line 5977
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /build/opencv/src/opencv-3.2.0/modules/imgproc/src/imgwarp.cpp:5977: error: (-215) src.cols > 0 && src.rows > 0 in function warpAffine

Comment: This assertion means that your input image to `warpAffine` is empty. You should debug the code to see what image is being passed to the function.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To help people answer your question, you'll need to be more specific about the error.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the exact errors you get from your [mcve] (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

Comment: Sorry i made a mistake, the right error was: OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (_matches.size()>1) in estimateTransformation, file /build/opencv/src/opencv-3.2.0/modules/shape/src/aff_trans.cpp, line 193
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /build/opencv/src/opencv-3.2.0/modules/shape/src/aff_trans.cpp:193: error: (-215) _matches.size()>1 in function estimateTransformation
it is given from the line before return 1;  img1Points and img2Points are std::vector<cv::Point> with 300 entries.

Comment: From the documentation it seems that the function expects `matches` as input but in your code `matches` is empty when passed to `estimateTransformation` function.

Comment: @FranzKaiser All updates and clarifications should be edited into the original question itself rather than in comments.

Comment: @beaker thank you for the tip, I canged the question.

Answer (score 2):

I have used AffineTransformer class on a 2D image. Below is the basic code which will give you an idea of what it does.

```
// My OpenCv AffineTransformer demo code
// I have tested this on a 500 x 500 resolution image
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include <vector>
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int arrSize = 10;
int sourcePx[]={154,155,159,167,182,209,238,265,295,316};
int sourcePy[]={190,222,252,285,314,338,344,340,321,290};
int tgtPx[]={120,127,137,150,188,230,258,285,305,313};
int tgtPy[]={207,245,275,305,336,345,342,332,305,274};

int main()
{
    // Prepare 'vector of points' from above hardcoded points
    int sInd=0, eInd=arrSize;
    vector<Point2f> sourceP; for(int i=sInd; i<eInd; i++) sourceP.push_back(Point2f(sourcePx[i], sourcePy[i]));
    vector<Point2f> tgtP; for(int i=sInd; i<eInd; i++) tgtP.push_back(Point2f(tgtPx[i], tgtPy[i]));

    // Create object of AffineTransformer
    bool fullAffine = true; // change its value and see difference in result
    auto aft = cv::createAffineTransformer(fullAffine);

    // Prepare vector<cv::DMatch> - this is just mapping of corresponding points indices
    std::vector<cv::DMatch> matches;
    for(int i=0; i<sourceP.size(); ++i) matches.push_back(cv::DMatch(i, i, 0));

    // Read image
    Mat srcImg = imread("image1.jpg");
    Mat tgtImg;

    // estimate points transformation
    aft->estimateTransformation(sourceP, tgtP, matches);
    // apply transformation
    aft->applyTransformation(sourceP, tgtP);
    // warp image
    aft->warpImage(srcImg, tgtImg);
    // show generated output
    imshow("warped output", tgtImg);
    waitKey(0);

    return 0;
}
```